# Twitter/X status post using LinqToTwitter is stuck

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-twitter

So I am using the below code to post a status update to X (formerly Twitter).  It is using the LinqToTwitter library created by Joe Mayo in C#.  Note that I have verified 4 times that all of the tokens/keys/secrets are correct on the X Developer Portal.  When I call the "tweet" method and pass a string, the code runs with no errors, but the status update is never posted to my X feed.  I think the code is stuck and never actually runs when it calls await twitterCtx.TweetAsync(message); Any ideas what I am doing wrong or missing?  Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated, as I have been trying to get this to work for a week now.

```
public void tweet(string message)
{
sendTweet(message);
}

static async void sendTweet(string message)
{
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
{
    CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
    {
        ConsumerKey = "####################",
        ConsumerSecret = "####################",
        AccessToken = "####################",
        AccessTokenSecret = "####################",
        OAuthToken = "####################",
        OAuthTokenSecret = "####################"
    }
};

var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

await twitterCtx.TweetAsync(message);
}
```